# How can i implement API gateway in micro services

Tags: api-gateway

I have developed my microservices in springboot, want to implement API gateway in it.
My frontend is Angular.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. How can I doesn't exists here. First you provide something you already tried and then we could investigate with you. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial platform. Internet is full for such things

Answer (score 0):

Read in detail from here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/gateway/

(All about how to create and config gateway in spring-boot.)